# passing modified array values back to main function in C++

Tags: c++

Write a reverse function that takes an integer array and its length as arguments. Your 
function should reverse the contents of the array, leaving the reversed values in the original 
array, and return nothing.

```
 #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void printArray(int a[], const int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i];
            i!=n-1 ? cout<<", " : cout<<"";
        }
    }

    void reverse(int a[], const int n)
    {
        int reverse[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            reverse[n-1-i]=a[i];
        }
        a = reverse;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int *a,n;
        cin>>n;
        a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=0;
        a[0]=1;
        reverse(a,n);
        printArray(a,n);
        delete [] a;
        a = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
```

After calling reverse function the array from main is not modifying, please advice! :(

Comment: You have to pass the array by reference, not by value.

Comment: @Jamal but also avoid the memory leak and potentially referencing a dead object

Comment: @vlad: Oh yeah, `new` is used here as well.  I missed that.

Comment: Worded very much like a homework assignment to me!

Comment: @Skizz: I suppose that also explains why `using namespace std` is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not copying the data from `reverse` back to `a` - you are instead pointing it (`a`) to a memory location that will no longer exist (be valid) after your function returns. You need to copy the values from `reverse` back to `a`. And I would recommend not using the same name for a function and a variable.

Try

```
void reverse(int a[], const int n)
{
    int reverse[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        reverse[n-1-i]=a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=reverse[i];
    }
}
```

As was pointed out in comments, the above shows *one* way of getting the reversed data into array `a`. It is not the only way - `memcpy` is considered a more efficient function to use. Even more efficient would be to do *in place* reversal - this would require a loop of just `n/2` iterations while the above loops for `2n` and is thus about 4x less efficient.

I recommend that you study all the answers provided - they highlight different aspects of memory handling, code efficiency etc.; something to learn from all of them.

Comment: Or with a single `for-loop`:  `for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i) { std::swap(a[i], a[n - i - 1]); }`

Comment: From the way the question is worded, it sounds like they're looking for an in-place reversal of the elements, but that could just be me. Still, in-place is surely preferable to allocate and copy?

Comment: I agree that in-place reversal would be preferable. I was trying to "change as little code as possible" since OP seems to be trying to understand "what is wrong with `a = reverse;`?" rather than "do my homework for me so I get an A". @ZacHowland's method is obviously more efficient.

Comment: @Floris:  Understood ... I was just mentioning it for completeness.  It would be beneficial for the OP to understand that his solution effectively requires iterating through the array `2 * N` times ... while the swap method only requires iterating through the array `N / 2` times.

Answer (score 5):

You can't assign one array to another. Instead *copy* from `reverse` to back into `a`:

```
std::copy(reverse, reverse + n, a);
```

Or possibly

```
memcpy(a, reverse, n * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers! They're really useful.

```
void reverse (int *a, const size_t n)
{
  int *b = a + n - 1;
  while (b > a)
  {
    const int swap_value = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = swap_value;
    ++a;
    --b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bonus points if you modify it to only require a single increment per iteration instead of an increment and decrement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, you know you should pass `int a[]`, a pointer to `a`, to `reverse()`, but you still encounter the same problem. You can't modify the pointer stored in `a`, unless you pass &a to `reverse()`.

Comment: And even if he did - that memory location will not be valid after the function returns.

Comment: Yeah, it's stack memory